# Access route not found when trying to call a file added in my solution explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, resources

```
public class Hero
{

    XPathNavigator Navigator;
    XPathDocument HeroInformation;        

    public string GetHeroIcon(string Name)
    {            
        XDocument HeroInformation = XDocument.Load("InformationRepositories/HeroRepository/HeroInformation.xml");
        return HeroInformation.Descendants(Name).Single().Element("Icon").Value;
        //return doc.Descendants(name).Single().Element("Icon").Value;
    }

}
```

I get an error in the first line of my method. I don't understand why it's not working when the adress is clearly written correctly. I'm so confused with this.

Here's a picture of my solution explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `XDocument.Load()` method has seeems to search for the requested file in the Bin/debug folder.
you need do this to find the check the file at correct location.

```
XDocument HeroInformation = XDocument.Load("../../InformationRepositories/HeroRepository/HeroInformation.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

When your application executes, it is executing from either the bin/Debug or bin/Release directory by default. The path you are trying to follow starts at those directories. You can use the full qualifying path or copy the file/folder structure into the Debug/Release directory. You can also set your application to compile to a different directory. `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will get you the directory you are executing from, and from there you can use `Path.Combine` to figure out the location you are looking for the file.